# Calculating checkboxes Apple Numbers after filtering

Tags: excel-formula, numbers, formula, calculation

In my numbers worksheet I create a table with the columns name, date and a column with checkboxes.

And a second table with a cell that counts the checkboxes they returned true. I used this formule COUNTIF(A;WAAR)

Now I created a filter on the column date but If I activate the filter the COUNTIF count all checkboxes if they are true and not only the filtered checkboxes with true.

Who knows how I can create this in Apple Numbers?

Answer (score 1):

In Excel there is a function that allows you to do this. You can find further information on why `countif` does not yield the result you are looking for and which alternatives you have [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/countif-visible-cells-in-filter-mode.56984/). A similar solution does not seem to exist in Apple Numbers (see [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250236958)).

You could add another column that turns 0 or 1 depending on whether you selected the specific date in a row and then reference this column in your `sumif`.